# Copy Folder (only copy the python files, but not the rest)

Tags: linux, copy

How do I copy the a folder (only its python files) while maintaining the structure? How do I do this in command line?

Comment: `cp -r folder/*.py .` - what do you mean by maintaing the structure?

Comment: """
folder:
     - subfolder1
             - abc.py
     - subfolder 2
             -subsubfolder2
                     -efg.py
"""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure